# Issues with missing ")" after argument list in truffle testing

Tags: javascript, testing, solidity, truffle, decentralized-applications

I am trying to test a solidity contract using truffle test suite and I am unable to fix my code. The error reads " Issues with missing ")" after argument list in truffle testing.".  I'd greatly appreciate any feedback or help as I have pretty much hit a wall and am unsure how to proceed. I've also added a screenshot of the error I'm receiving. [Error stack photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG25L.jpg)  [GitHub repository with both the solidity contract and test file](https://github.com/Rooseveltthedev/CourseraDocs)

Answer (score 0):

Edit in line 57

> });

to this:

> )})});

Also you can use these VS Code extensions to follow brackets and indents:

[indent-rainbow](https://Also%20you%20can%20use%20these%20VS%20Code%20extensions%20to%20follow%20parenthesis:%20VS%20Marketplace%20Link:%20https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?)

[Rainbow Brackets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=2gua.rainbow-brackets)